# Problem in exporting .apk file (Could not access the digital certificate - unable to load a certificate)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

[image]

I had created a .p12 certificate file in Adobe CS6 in 2015.

I was later using Adobe Animate CC 2016 to export the .apk file with the same certificate to update the app in Google-play.

Recently, I was trying to update the app but Google Play needed SDK 28 or later.

So, I updated to Adobe Animate 2019 and I'm getting this error now.

Comment: Did you try to export you apk by command line?
Here is the sample:

"%aircompiler%\bin\adt.bat" -package -target apk-captive-runtime  -storetype pkcs12 -storepass %android_pass% -keystore "%android_certificate%" "%exportname%.apk" "%android_xml_name%.xml" "%swfname%.swf" %contents% %native_folder%

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to update java in:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2016\jre
   ```
2. You need to download `server-jre-8u211-windows-x64` from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html).
3. Open the file that you downloaded and copy (jre) folder and put it in this location:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate CC 2016\ (New jre)
   ```

Then everything is right.

Answer (score 0):

Packaging an Android app fails on computers having Java 8 when using an RSA-1024 certificate created with the Adobe AIR Developer Tool (ADT). [Read More](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/rsa1024-certificate-issue-with-adt-tool.html)

1. install java 7 in your computer.
2. copy entire "jre" folder from ProgramFiles/java in  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate 2020\jre.
3. now you cand reinstall java 8 in your computer